# Car Classification - Keras InceptionV3 Modification - Val acc not going over 45%

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multiclass-classification

I want to use the pretrained InceptionV3 weights from imagenet to build my modified CNN for car classification. The dataset is from Stanford University and comes with 196 classes to classify. I don't include the top when importing so I can add my last Dense layer with 196 neurons. I tried a lot of variations but the val_acc is not going over 45%.

The dataset includes 8103 images to train and 8000 images to validate.
[Stanford Dataset](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Ejkrause/cars/car_dataset.html)

I want to use transfer learning that's why I try to use the pretrained weights.

Like this I'm building my train and validation batches.

```
train_data_gen = image_generator_train.flow_from_directory(directory=str(data_dir_train),
                                                     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                     class_mode="categorical",
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     color_mode="rgb",
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                     classes = list(car_models)
                                                    )
```

Importing & modifying the InceptionV3:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau

InceptionV3Model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
    weights='imagenet',
    include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(299,299,3)),
    classes=1000
)

for layer in InceptionV3Model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = InceptionV3Model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(2048)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1024)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, use_bias=False)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(196, activation='softmax')(x)
InceptionV3Model = Model(inputs=InceptionV3Model.input, outputs=x)

InceptionV3Model.summary()

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
InceptionV3Model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min')
mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('./Models/model_05_07_weights.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
reduce_lr_loss = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=7, verbose=1, min_delta=1e-4, mode='min')

history = InceptionV3Model.fit(
    train_data_gen, 
    epochs=20, 
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, 
    validation_data=test_data_gen, 
    validation_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TEST, #100
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=True, 
    callbacks=[earlyStopping, mcp_save, reduce_lr_loss]
)

# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[history of training after 20epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F12WI.png)

The picture shows the model after 20 epochs.

I tried different Dense layers, changed order of BatchNorm and Dropout, different Dropout factors.
I'm pretty new to this topic but need to finish the project soon for my studies so I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The validation loss and accuracy plateaus at around one third of your epochs while the training values keep getting better. This is an indicator for overfitting of the model.

This means the variance of the model needs to be reduced. Or the number of images needs to be increased. This is what you could do about it:

1. Freeze the weights of the first couple of layers.
2. 8000 images to train on 196 classes means roughly 40 images per class. That's not very much. Try data augmentation with Keras ImageDataGenerator.

Comment: Do you mean freezing Dense(2048) and Dense(1024)? I'm freezing the pretrained InceptionV3 layers already. Thank you! I'll try data augmentation

Comment: Sorry, no you should not freeze those layers. Here are some ideas what you could do with those layers: reduce the number of neurons per layer, Increase dropout, Try the model with only one or two additional hidden layers Instead of your three.